# Replace multiple possible characters in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to ask about replacing multiple possible characters in excel.
I have some cells containing coordinates like:

> (37.286.866, 16.826.515)
>
> (36.491.603, 17.624.765)
>
> (37.297.949, 16.951.373)

I would like to get their value in a new cell without the parentheses and (if possible) the space between like:

> 37.286.866,16.826.515

To make it clear in a cell both coordinates are included. For example *A1* cell contains `(37.286.866, 16.826.515)`
I tried something like (with the intention of using another embedded `SUBSTITUTE` after that) but is does not seem to work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;"(";"-")
```

Although there is no error just a blank cell.

Any idea how can I achieve this?
I am not interested in VB solutions if possible. Just an in-cell solution. The functionality I am looking (if this makes it any clearer) is similar to the regex `[()]` where any of the previous could be replaced.

I am using MS office 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is in cell B3 put the following formula in C3

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"(",""),")","")," ","")
```

[image]

Note that Excel on MS Windows uses list separator character as specified in Windows Control Panel --> Regional and Language --> Additional Settings --> List Separator. In case in your version of Windows it's set to ; (Semi Colon) instead of , (Comma) the formula would then become.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3;"(";"");")";"");" ";"")
```

Comment: Well, it works with `;` instead of `,` of course. If you can change your answer it would be even better. Thanks

Comment: @Eypros - Answer updated. Additionally mentioned about List Separator character and also have shown the formula with ; (Semi Colon) as list separator instead of , (Comma)

Comment: Unfortunately, the upper limit of substitute functions to be used in one cell is 8. But what if you have more than 8 strings to substitute?